# Dreamweaver Regex: Replace dumb quotes with curly (typographic) quotes

Tags: html, regex

Does anybody know how to replace the HTML entity for dumb (straight) double quote marks (`&quot;`) with curly typographic html entites - `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;` respectively?

I only know the basics of regex at the moment and was hoping that there were some good dreamweaver find-and-replace tutorials but so far have found nothing useful.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Find:
`&quot;((.|\s)*?)&quot;`

Replace:
`&ldquo;$1&rdquo;`

The regex says to look for "&quot;" followed by any amount of any character or whitespace (without being greedy), followed by another "&quot;".

You should be absolutely sure that the &quot; symbols always come in pairs. Otherwise you might end up with odd results.

Comment: Dude you just saved me a lot of time.